# api server - queue service vs local mini queue

Tags: node.js, amazon-sqs, api-design

I built an API server in node js, which is supposed to work under heavy load. I basically want to accumulate incoming insert requests in small batches (about 10 items each), and once a batch is filled, insert the items to the database. At the moment I'm using Amazon SQS as my queue service, and a separate queue consumer application that I designed. However, I thought maybe I can accumulate the messages locally and then insert the batch directly from the API. This would eliminate the overhead of the communication with the remote queue service, and since the batches are small, the memory of the API server won't be inflated. What do you think? pros and cons?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned to have heavy load on your server. If you try to implement queue to collect incoming requests then it could end up consuming huge memory on your server. Until you have self scale up capability, it would always be a risk. You should consider following:
- total batch size 
- max size of each request
This would help you to prevent out of memory issues.

other considerations should be:
- is it a distributed/clustered environment? If yes then think about if 2 requests are related and do you want to club them together on one sever?
- timer: does your queue has any timer mechanism. I can see that i't db insert so is there a scenario that an insert can't wait for a batch to complete to write in db. If yes then implement timer to persist (irrespective of batch is full or not)
- Check if server got spike attacks, would your queuing mechanism would be able to handle it well? anything like spike out policy.
- does system failure is a concern where you may lost partial batch insert data?
- I can see that by doing this you are trying to save transit time for remote call. But if you blocking requests to get persisted (in a batch), do you really care for transit time (real concern)? If not then SQS is more reliable & efficient solution.

other than these, try to prevent your system from sql injection attacks.